# Formatting a query to enumerate through 2 different datatables

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have 2 datatables `sendTable` and `recvTable`

They both have identical column names and numbers of columns

> "NODE" "DSP Name" "BUS" "IDENT" "STATION" "REF1" "REF2" "REF3" "REF4" "REF5" "REF6" "REF7" "REF8"

I need to compare these 2 tables and separate out the mismatches, checking only columns 3-11 and ignoring cols 1 and 2

I tried at first removing the 2 columns and then loop thru row by row and return matches and mismatches but the problem with this approach is that I no longer have the "NODE" and "DSP Name" associated with the row when I finalize my results

So I need help with a query

Here is my attempt

```
var samerecordQuery = from r1 in sendTable.AsEnumerable()
                      where r1.Field<int>("BUS").Equals(from r2 in recvTable.AsEnumerable() where r2.Field<int>("BUS"))
```

this obviously doesn't work so how do I format the query to say

```
from r1 cols[3-11] equals r2 cols [3-11]
```

and once I have this I can use the except to pull out the mismatches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var matched = 
    from s in sendTable.AsEnumerable()
    join r in recvTable.AsEnumerable() on
        new {BUS = s.Field<int>("BUS"), IDENT = s.Field<int>("IDENT"),...} equals
        new {BUS = r.Field<int>("BUS"), IDENT = r.Field<int>("IDENT"),...}
    select new {Send = s, Receive = r};
```

this matches the records in both tables based on whatever columns you need and returns matched records grouped.

Comment: It gives me the error r1 is not in scope on the right side of the equals

Comment: See my edited query, I was using your identifiers r1 and r2, they should be s and r. Also you would have to add the other columns to the join statement; that is why I have the "..." at the end of every "new" declaration.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution

```
var matched = from s in sendTable.AsEnumerable()
                     join r in recvTable.AsEnumerable() on
                     new { BUS = s.Field<int>("BUS"), 
                           IDENT = s.Field<int>("IDENT"), 
                           STATION = s.Field<int>("STATION"), 
                           REF1 = s.Field<string>("REF1"), 
                           REF2 = s.Field<string>("REF2"),
                           REF3 = s.Field<string>("REF3"),
                           REF4 = s.Field<string>("REF4"),
                           REF5 = s.Field<string>("REF5"),
                           REF6 = s.Field<string>("REF6"),
                           REF7 = s.Field<string>("REF7"),
                           REF8 = s.Field<string>("REF8") } equals
                      new { BUS = r.Field<int>("BUS"), 
                           IDENT = r.Field<int>("IDENT"), 
                           STATION = r.Field<int>("STATION"), 
                           REF1 = r.Field<string>("REF1"), 
                           REF2 = r.Field<string>("REF2"),
                           REF3 = r.Field<string>("REF3"),
                           REF4 = r.Field<string>("REF4"),
                           REF5 = r.Field<string>("REF5"),
                           REF6 = r.Field<string>("REF6"),
                           REF7 = r.Field<string>("REF7"),
                           REF8 = r.Field<string>("REF8") } 
                     select new { Send = s, Receive = r };
```